# Isolated Scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my custom directive code

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('CustDirMod', []);
    var custdirCtrl = function ($scope) {
        $scope.Person = {
            Name: 'Jagan868',
            address: {
                street: '10 Donwstreet',
                city: 'North Avenue',
                state: 'Los Angeles'
            },
            friends: [
                'Friend1',
                'Friend2',
                'Friend3'
            ]
        };
    };
    var custDirectivewithBinding = function () {

        return {
            templateUrl: "Friends.html",
            restrict: "E",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.KnightMe = function (Person) {
                    Person.rank = "Knight";
                }
            }
        }
    };
    app.controller('CustDirCtrl', custdirCtrl);
    app.directive("custDirectiveBinding", custDirectivewithBinding);
})();
```

and here is my template html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        {{ Person.Name }}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-show='!!Person.address'>
            <h4>Address :
            </h4>
            {{Person.address.street}}
            <br />
            {{Person.address.city}}
            <br />
            {{Person.address.state}}
        </div>
        <h4>Friends :</h4>
        <br />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='friend in Person.friends'>
                {{friend}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-show="!!Person.rank">
            Rank : {{Person.rank}}
        </div>
        <button ng-show="!Person.rank" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="KnightMe(Person)">Knight Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the following final html page where i'm using the above custom directive

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="CustDirMod">
<head>
    <title>Simple Directives - Angularjs</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-1.5.8.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CustomDirective.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CustDirCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <cust-directive-binding></cust-directive-binding><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Now i tried to add isolated scope in my custom directive as follows

```
var custDirectivewithBinding = function () {

        return {
            templateUrl : "Friends.html",
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                userdata: "="
            },
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.KnightMe = function (Person) {
                    Person.rank = "Knight";
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

and then in the html page as follows

```
<body ng-controller="CustDirCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px;">
    <cust-directive-binding userdata="Person"></cust-directive-binding><br /><br />
</body>
```

After adding the isolated scope named as 'userdata' i'm not getting any data in UI. But if i remove that 'userdata' isolated scope from both js & html file its working fine. How to resolve this issue.

P.S: I don't want name the isolated scope local property name same as "Person". I just want it to be something different so that i can distinguish easily.

Comment: in your template you use Person. replace it with userdata.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a scope property `Person` in the directive , you renamed it to `userdata` when you created the isolated scope.

You either need to change the template to now use `userdata` instead of `Person` or change the name of `userdata` to `Person` so the template will work

```
scope: {
      userdata: "="
 }
  // in view 
 {{ userdata.Name}}
```

Or

```
<cust-directive-binding Person="Person">

scope: {
      Person: "="
}
// in view 
 {{ Person.Name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because now inside your directive template data will be available with isolated scope variable `userdata`. To fix the issue you could use `userdata` instead of `Person` every where on template. But instead of doing that I'd suggest you to use alias on isolated scope like `Person: "=userdata"`. Where it says `userdata` will be attribute inside directive data will be available with `Person` name.

```
scope: {
   Person: "=userdata"
},
```